# drupal module secure pages toggles between http and https on reload

Tags: 7, security

I am using the secure pages drupal module to enable https for some of the pages , but i have noticed one bug in this , each time i reload the page its toggling between http and https, and if i go from a secure page to another secure page(ex: login to registration which are bith secure according to settings) the destination page will be in http but if i refresh it toggles between secure and non secure , a similar issue is reported [here](http://drupal.org/node/420712)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the problem could be in several places, depending on which webserver you're using, how it's configured, etc.

Are you using Apache with mod_ssl?  NOthing else 'in front', like nginx doing the SSL handshaking instead?

In any case, I'm guessing that your webserver's not consistenly serving up the required server var.  In 'securepages.module', there's a check for

```
return (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

Not knowing your webserver config, find out what your webserver is doing.  add,

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

to your pages and look to see what the values of

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS']
$_SERVER[SERVER_PORT]
```

are.  Or simply print them out directly ...  Check if/how those values toggle on page refresh.

I'm suspicious of caching, too.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that they donot toggle between http and https, go to secure pages and let say you want to make a specific link 'mylink' secure. Write (use aesterik and forward slash before link and (forward slash and aesterik) after your link) in the list of secured pages to ensure that it is secured. I did it in multilingual site and it worked for me.

Posted this thing so that any one can take advantage of it. :)